# Python/CGI/Ajax: cgi.FieldStorage does not receive arguments

Tags: javascript, python, ajax, cgi

I am trying to get a Python, cgi module, ajax/javascript combination to work. Due to the nature of my server access (essentially rented webspace), I cannot install things like django or any other webframework. I am stuck with cgi for now. I am able to call the python file to simply print out something, but once it comes to passing an argument to the python file the cgi.FieldStorage() does not receive any input. When I add a print statement for the FieldStorage, the output is as follows:

```
FieldStorage(None, None, [])
```

You can find all the necessary code below. Essentially, all I am trying to do (for testing purposes) is to get a string from a text input, add a "1" to the end of it and return it.

Interestingly, when I use a simple php file that does the exact same thing and use it in the otherwise exact same script, the script works without any issues. Here's a typical php script that I tried:

```
<?php
$user = urldecode(implode(file('php://input')));
$adj_user = $user . "1";
echo $adj_user;
?>
```

(Please note that I want to use python, because I am far more comfortable with it and I dislike php quite a bit.)

I have the feeling that I am just a little bit dense and it is something very simple. Any help in finding what I am doing wrong is very appreciated. Thanks a lot in advance!

P.S. I have scoured stackoverflow and the web quite some time before I posted on here. There are many related topics, but nothing quite as (seemingly) simple as what I am asking. If there is an answered duplicate to this question then I apologise and would be grateful for a link. Thanks again.

The traceback is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/www/xxxxx/html/cgi-bin/hello.py", line 14, in &lt;module&gt;
    adj_user = form['user'] +  "1"
  File "/usr/lib/python2.5/cgi.py", line 567, in __getitem__
    raise KeyError, key
KeyError: 'user'
```

Here is the "index.html"

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
    <title>Report</title>
    <script type='text/javascript' src='test.js'></script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <form method="post" action=""> 

    <p>Please enter your name here:
    <input type="text" name="user">

    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" onClick="return hello(this.form.user.value);">
    </p>

    </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

This is the "test.js" file:

```
function hello(user) {
    // Mozilla version
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
        xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
// IE version
    else if (window.ActiveXObject) {
        xhr = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    //user=encodeURIComponent(user);
    xhr.open("POST", "../cgi-bin/hello.py");
    xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type','application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8');
    xhr.send(user);

    xhr.onreadystatechange=function() {
        if (xhr.readyState===4) {
            adj_user = xhr.responseText;
            alert ("Hello " + adj_user);
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

and lastly "hello.py" in my server's cgi-bin

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: UTF-8 -*-

import cgi
form = cgi.FieldStorage()

# enable debugging
import cgitb
cgitb.enable()

print "Content-Type: text/html;charset=utf-8"
print

adj_user = form['user'] +  "1"
print adj_user
```

---

*EDIT*

I made some progress, but it still isn't what I am hoping for. I changed the following block as follows:

```
    xhr.open("GET", "../cgi-bin/hello.py?user=" + user, true);
    xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type','application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8');
    xhr.send();
```

Please note the change from POST to GET and the suffix ' "?user=" + user ', as well as the removal of the 'user' argument in the send() method.

Now this does, what I want, but it just shouldn't "be" that way. There must be a way to get this to work the classical way...

As usual, any attempt or suggestion is welcome. I really don't know what else to try. Thanks fellas.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The format of `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` data is:

```
key=value&key2=value2
```

… where the keys and values are URL encoded.

You are posting just the value of a field, with no keys.

```
var postData = encodeURIComponent('user') + '=' + encodeURIComponent(user);
xhr.send(postData);
```

The reason that the PHP code was working was because you was reading the raw POST data instead of `$_POST['user']` (which is what your Python was equivalent to).

You also need to access `form['user'].value` rather than `form['user']`. That will return a `str` so you can't concatenate it with `+ 1` without performing type conversion.

Comment: Thanks so much for your answer! Unfortunately, I don't quite understand what you mean and I can't get my code to work with what you have written. (I just exchanged the lines in my code with the 'postData' variable minus the unclosed ' etc.)
Could you maybe write out the code block in question for me. I am still fairly new to ajax so bear with me. Thanks!

Comment: On the JavaScript side, just replace the send line with the two lines above. I found issues with the Python side too, and have updated the answer.

Comment: Thanks, man. That did it. it is still not as dynamic as I hoped for. I still have to write out a 

"encodeURIComponent('key') + '=' + encodeURIComponent(key)" code block for each variable passed, which can become quite long if you have 3 or more, but I will mark your answer as accepted. Thanks mate, you're a star! 

I'll award the +50 to you once I can (22 hours apparently), unless, of course, someone comes up with a dynamic way of entering the keys.

Comment: You don't need to do that for each line, that is what arrays are for.

Comment: Such— http://jsbin.com/ujucoc/1/ —although I haven't done any of the special casing you would need for selects, checkboxes, radios, and buttons.

Comment: That definitely answered my question, mate. Thanks a lot! Keep up the good work :)